# NET STOP - domino as service and interactive window

Tags: windows-service, ibm-domino

1) i have domino running as service .

2) i have java console running to monitor server

3) i want to stop domino using NET STOP but without interactive message on java console

"are you sure you want quit the Domino Server Controller and/or Domino Server running (if running)?"

Press 'Y' to continue and 'N' to cancell

Q: how can i disable or bypass this message ?

thanks for your help.

Comment: `net stop /y`??

Comment: Domino version? Windows Server version?

Comment: Maybe usefull for you would be the "Domino Maintenance Script" on OpenNTF here: http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Domino%20Maintenance%20Script

Answer (score 2):

You can run `net stop /y` to suppress the yes/no prompt.

Simple enough.